# LineString - get coordinates as DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geopandas, shapely

I have a geopandas Dataframe with one `GeoSeries`.

There is only one entry for this column, a `shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString`.

```
LineString (first_lon first_lat, second_lon second_lat, ...)
```

I could not find an easy way to get the coordinates of this `LineString` as a DataFrame like

```
LON           LAT
first_lon     first_LAT
second_lon    second_LAT
...
```

Is there a build in function for this?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x,y = LineStringObject.coords.xy
pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x,y)), columns=['LAT', 'LON'])
```

seem to do the job ok.

[EDIT]

```
x,y = LineStringObject.coords.xy
pd.DataFrame({'LAT':x,'LON':y})
```

Comment: Wouldn't this work just fine without the `list()` ? What does `LineStringObject.coords.xy` look like, why are you unpacking the result?

Comment: `LineStringObject.coords.xy` are of type `tuple`.


`x,y` are `arrays`.

Did not get it to work without the zip